# Spring @Configuration behavior with @Autowired field

Tags: java, spring, dependency-injection, configuration, autowired

I was expecting following code to throw some kind of Initialization or Circular dependency exception but it seems to work. I can `@Autowire` `SomeOtherBean` in other classes and I checked that it wasn't `null`.

```
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
@Configuration
public class MyConfig {

    @Autowired
    private MyBean myBean;

    @Bean
    public MyBean  createMyBean() {
    return new MyBean();
    }

    @Bean
    public SomeOtherBean createSomeOtherBean() {
        return new SomeOtherBean(this.myBean);
    }
}
```

[3.4.1.3 Dependency resolution process](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#d0e2299) says,

*You can generally trust Spring to do the right thing. It detects configuration problems, such as references to non-existent beans and circular dependencies, at container load-time. Spring sets properties and resolves dependencies as late as possible, when the bean is actually created. This means that a Spring container which has loaded correctly can later generate an exception when you request an object if there is a problem creating that object or one of its dependencies.*

I'm not sure how this applies to my code. Can someone help me understand this better?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'd assume myBean is set by calling createMyBean, which also happens to be used by createSomeOtherBean. Where do you think there's a circular dependency?

Comment: Note that you wouldn't want to do it this way. Instead you should do `new SomeOtherBean(createMyBean());`.

Comment: It's unclear what you're asking. Spring manages to resolve the dependency graph here successfully, so what's the problem?

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis Or, IMO even more preferable, `public SomeOtherBean createSomeOtherBean(MyBean myBean)`.

Comment: Yeah, that's preferable.

Comment: @DennisHunziker - So how does Spring know that it is okay to call `createMyBean` without resolving the `@Autowired` field but before calling `createSomeOtherBean` it needs to resolve the same field.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis - I agree and I don't actually intend to use this code as it is. I am just trying to understand the behavior in this case.